# Im trying to make a discord bot that sends a message reminding people that our secret santa is in 1 week but its isnt working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tried what I remembered but I'm still fairly new to discord.py so I can't spot what the problem is.

```py
import discord
import os
import asyncio, datetime
from keep_alive import keep_alive

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

asyncio.datetime.datetime((2021, 12, 10, 20, 41)                 
  channel = (894709862091591724)
  channel.message.send('@everyone the secret santa is in 1 week!'))

client = MyClient()
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: I highly recommend you check out these two links: [Getting started with discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) and [Using Commands in discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html). This should give you a better idea of how you can use `discord.py`. Furthermore, there are hundreds of tutorials on youtube that can assist you with starting out.

Comment: @Roopesh-J thank you i will try that out

Comment: Yep, you could probably make a command that like DMs every person participating or mentions them. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send messages automatically (*for example every day*). You can use [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop) for it. It will run every 24 hours and send your message.

Also, if you make a simple bot and you don't have to use classes it's much easier to create a client with [`client = commands.Bot()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) instead of making a class. You also have to use [`client.get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel) or [`await client.fetch_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch%20channel#discord.Client.fetch_channel) to use channel.

```py
# imports you need
import discord, asyncio, datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") # creating client

@tasks.loop(hours=24) # you can change it to minutes or seconds too
async def secret_santa():
    santa = datetime.date(2021, 12, 6) # your date (year, month, day)
    today = datetime.date.today() # gets today's date
    delta = (santa - today).days # calculates number of days to "santa" (I used ".days" to get only number of days)
                
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(894709862091591724)
    await channel.send(f'@everyone the secret santa is in {delta} days')

secret_santa.start() # starting task
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: when i try to run this code it says, 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    client = commands.Bot() # creating client
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command_prefix'

Comment: You're right. I accidentally removed it.  I edited my answer. You can change `!` to any prefix you want.